# Nginx: is there any reason to *not* enable 'keepalive' with upstream server?

Tags: nginx

Reading http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive
it seems that this configuration should always be enabled (even if only set to 1) as it can only increase performance. But if it was the case the default would probably not be to be disabled, so what are the potential gotchas?